# 日本郵便の住所とe-Statの住所を紐づける方法

Tags: pandas

[日本郵便が配布している郵便番号,住所テーブル](https://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/download.html)と[e-Statが提供しているshpファイル](https://www.e-stat.go.jp/gis/statmap-search?page=1&type=2&aggregateUnitForBoundary=A&toukeiCode=00200521&toukeiYear=2015&serveyId=A002005212015&prefCode=01&coordsys=2&format=shape)を用いて郵便番号-緯度経度テーブルを作成したいと考えてます。しかし、日本郵便とe-Statの住所表記に数多くの表記揺れが存在しており、簡単にジョインできない状況です。住所以外に共通するユニークなカラムが存在しないためどのようにすれば上手く結合できるかアイデアをいただきたく思い質問しました。個人的には文字類似度を使って文字同士を数値に変換して, 数値が高ければ高いほど類似度が近いものを結合するというやり方をしましたが、全て結合することはできませんでした。

今回の質問は北海道の市区町村を対象に郵便番号-緯度経度を作成できないか質問させていただきました。
使用したコードとファイルはここで展開するには大きすぎるため[github](https://github.com/ReiSato18/lat_lon)のレポジトリに置きました。
join_hokkaido.ipynbを用いて, 日本郵便番号テーブル:KEN_ALL_ROME.CSVとe-Statからスクレイピングしてテーブル化したHokkaido_latlon.csvファイルを読み込んでジョインします。

お手数ですが、こちらを参考に使用してください。

おすすめのパッケージなどもありましたらコメントでアドバイスお願いします。
ご不明点ございましたらコメントお願いします。

Comment: Pythonでも無くヒント程度の情報でしょうが、こんなモジュールや商業サービス・製品があるようです。[経産省発の npm モジュール！住所や電話番号の正規化、ジオコーディングなどができる IMI コンポーネントツールを試した！](https://blog.geolonia.com/2020/05/29/imi-tools.html), [住所正規化コンバータ](https://biz.kkc.co.jp/software/geo/addressmatch/function/), [日本郵便が公開する郵便番号データをそのまま利用するのがなぜ難しいか。そして、住所から郵便番号を求めるのがなぜ難しいか［PR］](https://www.publickey1.jp/blog/17/yubin7_pr.html)

Comment: 国土地理協会では町字コードと郵便番号データを販売しているようです。[住所マスター](https://www.kokudo.or.jp/master/001.html)